# How to count number of columns in each row?

Tags: python, excel, csv

Each rows have different number of columns but Column A is always file name and rest of columns are fields of that file.

Is there any way I could count number of columns for each row?

```
import csv
file=('C:/)
with open('C:/Count.csv','w',encoding='cp949',newline='') as testfile:
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
    for line in file:
        lst=[len(line)]
        csv_writer.writerow(lst)
```

Comment: With a question concerning data, you should always give a sample of the data. It will speed things up and avoid misinterpretations.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I wanted to but I do not know how. Is there any way I can upload sample of my file? Or just image?

Comment: I would cut and paste a few lines as a `code snippet`. That should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either choose to split on commas or open the file with `csv`.

I'd recommend the latter. Here's how you can do that:

```
file1 = ... # file to read
file2 = ... # file to write
with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'w', encoding='cp949', newline='') as f2:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f1)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f2)
    for row in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow([len([x for x in row if x])]) # non-null counts only
```

Open both files simultaneously, iterate over the file to read, count its columns using `len(row)` and then write it out.

Comment: First of all, thank you for fast response. But the thing is, it is writing 367 on every row. When I type row on shell, it returns last row of the file and there are only 7 actuall values and rest of them are ' '.

Comment: @DoHunKim Your csv has empty values. That is easy to rectify. Do [len(x for x in row if x)].

Comment: `[len(x for x in row if x)]` creates `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`. Doing `x=[x for x in row if x]` then `[len(x)]` works. Thanks!

Comment: @DoHunKim oh. my bad. Fixed that in my answer too. No problem! You can also upvote answers :)

Comment: Ok Thanks for kind answer ~